# Setting A Div Height Based on Picture Size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I'm filling three javascript arrays in my php code in order to save the dimensions of a photo and it's source. I'm then only displaying a 325x300 thumbnail of the image on my page assuming the dimensions are not equal to 325x300 using php.

When a user clicks on one of the thumbnails I would like it to open the full size image in the #largeImage div, and unhide it. So far, that works.

However, I'm running into trouble getting the dive to resize to the dimensions of the image.  I'm using php in order to get the dimensions (unless there's a better way to do it in jQuery). At this point the div does not resize and I'm not sure where to go from here. I've included the jquery and the output html from the php code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @import "album_style.css";
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var active_index;
            var source_image;
            var index;
            var style;

            $('#largeImage').hide();
            $('#imageBackground').hide();

            $('#gallery img').click(function() {
                index = parseInt( $(this).attr('value'));
                $('#largImage').height(parseInt(picture_y[index]) + 20);
                $('#largImage').width(parseInt(picture_x[index]) + 50);
                $('#largeImage img').attr('src', picture_list[index]);
                $('#largeImage').show() ;
                $('#imageBackground').show() ;
                active_index = index ;
            });

            $('.next').click(function( event ){
                active_index = active_index + 1;
                max_index = array_size - 1;
                if(active_index == array_size)
                {
                    active_index = 0 ;
                }
                source_image = $('#largeImage img').attr('src');
                var newSrc = $('#largeImage img').attr('src')
                    .replace(source_image, picture_list[ active_index]);
                $('#largeImage img').attr('src', newSrc);
            });

            $('.back').click(function(event) {
                active_index = active_index - 1;

                if( active_index < 0 )
                {
                    active_index = array_size - 1;
                }
                source_image = $('#largeImage img').attr('src') ;
                var newSrc = $('#largeImage img').attr('src')
                        .replace(source_image, picture_list[active_index]);
                $('#largeImage img').attr('src', newSrc);
            }) ;

            $('.close').click(function() {
                $('#largeImage').hide();
                $('#imageBackground').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <img src="websitebanner.jpg">
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="news.php">News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="events.php">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">The Team</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="roster.php">Roster</a></li>
                <li><a href="albums.php">Albums</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="sponsors.php">Sponsors</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="social.php">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class='pageHeader'>Test1</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var array_size = 3;
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var picture_list = new Array(array_size);
    var picture_x = new Array(array_size);
    var picture_y = new Array(array_size);
</script>

<div id='imageBackground'></div>

<div id='largeImage'>
    <input type='button' class='close' value='X'>
    <input type='button' class='back' value='<<'>
    <img src='Test1/Image3.jpg'>
    <input type='button' class='next' value='>>'>
</div>

<div id='gallery'>
    <div id='thumbpanel'>
        <img value='0' src='Thumbnails/Thumb_Image6.jpg'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            picture_list[0] = 'Albums/Test1/Image6.jpg';
            picture_x[0] = 386;
            picture_y[0] = 233;
        </script>
        <img value='1' src='Thumbnails/Thumb_Ellie 012.jpg'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            picture_list[1] = 'Albums/Test1/Ellie 012.jpg';
            picture_x[1] = 3264;
            picture_y[1] = 2448;
        </script>
        <img value='2' src='Albums/Test1/concealedjesspermit.jpg'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            picture_list[2] = 'Albums/Test1/concealedjesspermit.jpg';
            picture_x[2] = 325;
            picture_y[2] = 300;
        </script>
        Page 1
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS I'm using at the moment.  The div does not resize if I remove the size constraints in the jQuery block.

```
{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Finger+Paint);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One);
@font-face
{
    font-family: "DayPosterBlack";
    src: url('dayposterblack.tff');

}
body{
    background-color: #303030;
    background:#222 url(dark_wall.png);
}
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 425px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px auto;
    background:#303030;
}
.photobanner {
    height: 233px;
    width: 3550px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: bannermove 30s liner infinite;
    animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}
.photobanner img{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease ;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
@keyframes "bannermove" {
    0%{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100%{
        margin-left: -2125px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes "bannermove" {
    0%{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100%{
        margin-left: -2125px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
    0%{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100%{
        margin-left: -2125px;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
    0%{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100%{
        margin-left: -2125px;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
    0%{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100%{
        margin-left: -2125px;
    }
}
#nav {
 font-family: 'DayPosterBlack', normal;
 position: relative;
 background-color: black ;
 width: 1000px;
 height:25px;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#ffff33;
 margin: 0px auto;
 z-index: 10;

}

#nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding:0px;

}

#nav ul li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

#nav ul li a {
 text-align: center;
 padding:55px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#ffff33;
}

#nav ul li ul {
 display: none
}

#nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li a {
 display:block;
 background:#000000;
 color:#ffff33;
 width: 75px;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
 border-right: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
 background:#303030;
 color:#fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffff33
}
#controlpanel {
 font-family: 'russo one', normal;
 position: relative;
 background: url('carbon_black.jpg');
 width: 1000px;
 height:25px;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#ffff33;
 margin: 0px auto;
 z-index: 0;

}

#controlpanel ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding:0px;

}

#controlpanel ul li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

#controlpanel ul li a {
 text-align: center;
 padding:25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#ffff33;
}

#controlpanel ul li ul {
 display: none
}

#controlpanel ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

#controlpanel ul li:hover ul li a {
 display:block;
 background:#000000;
 color:#ffff33;
 width: 75px;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
 border-right: none;
}

#controlpanel ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
 background:#303030;
 color:#fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffff33
}
.album_container{
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
}
.album_box{
position: relative;
margin: 0px auto;
float: left;
text-align: center;
color: #ffff33;
width:325px;
height: 300px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.album_box a{
font-family: 'russo one', sans serif ;
color: #ffff33;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none ;

}
.album_box img{
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
display: block;
}
.album_box p{
font-family: 'russo one', sans serif;
color: #ffff33;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0px;
z-index: 200px;
display: block;
background-color: #101010;
top: 280px;
}
.spacer {

position: relative;

width: 12px;
}
#gallery{
margin: 10px auto;
width: 1000px;



}
#thumpanel{
float: left;
width: 1000px;
border: 3px outset #101010;
background: url('dark_wall copydarker.png');

}


#thumbpanel img{
position: relative;
float: left;
padding: 4px;
}

#imageBackground{
position: fixed;
background: #303030;
opacity: 0.6 ;
width: 1500px;
height: 2000px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: auto;
z-index: 20 ;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
transform: translate( -50%, -50%);

}
#largeImage{
position: fixed;

background: #202020 ;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: auto;
z-index: 25 ;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
transform: translate( -50%, -50%);

}
 #largeImage img{
position: absolute;
top: 0 ;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto ;

}
.return{
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
}
.back{
float: left;
position: relative;
margin-top: 240px;
margin-left: 20px;
background: #101010;
text-align: center;
color: #ffff33;
border: 2px outset #000000;
text-decoration: none;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
vertical-align: middle;



}
.next{
float: right;
position: relative;
margin-top: 240px;
margin-right: -15px;
background: #101010;
text-align: center;
color: #ffff33;
border: 2px outset #000000;
text-decoration: none;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.close{
float: right;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
background: #101010 ;
text-align: center;
color: #ffff33;
border: 2px outset #000000;
text-decoration: none;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}
#largeImage input [type='button']:hover{
background: #303030 ;

}
.data_container{
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 20px auto;

}
.data_entry{
position: relative ;
width: 1000px;
margin: 5px auto ;
}

.data_entry table{

margin: 0px auto;
font-size: 16px;
color: #ffff33 ;
}
.data_entry form{
background: url('dark_wall copydarker.png') ;
border: 3px outset #000000;
margin: 0px auto;
font-size: 16px;
color: #ffff33 ;

}
.success{
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
background: #ffff33 ;
margin: 5px auto ;
font-size: 20px;
}
.error{
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
background: #ff0000;
margin: 5px auto;
font-size: 20px;
}
.button{
margin: 5px auto ;
width: 180px;
display: block;
background: #101010;
text-align: center;
color: #ffff33;
border: 2px outset #000000;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.button a:hover{
background: #303030 ;
}
.bottom_button{
position: relative;
bottom: 0 ;
margin: 5px auto ;
width: 180px;
display: block;
background: #101010;
text-align: center;
color: #ffff33;
border: 2px outset #000000;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
float: bottom ;
}
.bottom_button a:hover{
background: #303030 ;
}
.confirm{
margin: 5px auto ;
width: 180px;
display: block;
background: #101010;
text-align: center;
color: #ffff33;
border: 2px outset #000000;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.confirm a:hover{
background: #303030;
}
.uploaded_photos{
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0px auto ;
background: url('dark_wall copydarker.png') ;
color: #ffff33 ;
text-align: center;
border: 2px outset #000000;
}
.uploaded_photos img{
width: 40% ;
height: 40%;
float: left;
margin: 10px;

}
.pageHeader{
text-align: center ;
color: #ffff33 ; 
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold ;
background-color: #000000;
font-family: 'russo one', sans serif;
width: 1000px;
height: 25px;
position: relative;
margin: 5px auto;
}
```

Comment: You getting any error?

Comment: It isn't the way to go. Don't use original images to display a thumbnail. Create a miniature for each image before once and for all.

Comment: right I'm using imagecopyresampled to generate a smaller image.  however, my clients want the ability to see the full size image in the manner listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lines:

```
$('#largImage').height(parseInt(picture_y[index]) + 20);
$('#largImage').width(parseInt(picture_x[index]) + 50);
```

and let #largeImage automatically resize to fit the image. You can control the maximum dimensions of #largeImage using CSS (max-width, max-height).

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  Not sure why but the div scales with the two buttons that are supposed to go on either side of the image but will not scale with the image.  Pretty confused at this point.

Comment: realized that i need to set height, width to auto in css.  this fixed the issue.  thank you.